# cant figure out how to interate over a list as a comparisson for an if statement

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement

I am trying to do the following:

I have a list of users I want to remove from the database in the variable "users_to_rm". and I have setup a function that iterates though the users usernames field[0] on the list "users_to_rm" and deletes all users beside the user in "excluded_user"

```
def remove_users(users_to_rm):
    """ Remove users and associated extensions that are no longer in the database  """
    excluded_user = "supervisor"
    for users in users_to_rm:
        if users[0] == excluded_user:
            pass
        else:
            payloads_user_rm = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "deleteUser", "id": "05", "params": {"username":' + '"' + str(users[0]) + '"' +'}}'

            result = requests.request("GET", ucware_cfg.url_admin_user, data=payloads_user_rm, headers=ucware_cfg.headers)
            Reports.log(Reports.LogLevel.INFO, "#########\nUser " + str(extensions[0]) + " removed", send_mail=False)
            log_http_result(result)
```

Now, I would like that the excluded_user variable to be a list of users like this:

excluded_user=["supervisor","testuser","testuser2"]

I would like my function to do the same as it is doing now, but check the list of users in excluded_user and pass all those in the list.

I hope I made any sense and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a set to store your `excluded_user` list, the search in a set is O(1) time complexity:

```
def remove_users(users_to_rm):

    """ Remove users and associated extensions that are no longer in the database  """
    excluded_user = {"supervisor","testuser","testuser2"}

    for users in users_to_rm:
        if users[0] not in  excluded_user:
            payloads_user_rm = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "deleteUser", "id": "05", "params": {"username":' + '"' + str(users[0]) + '"' +'}}'

            result = requests.request("GET", ucware_cfg.url_admin_user, data=payloads_user_rm, headers=ucware_cfg.headers)
            Reports.log(Reports.LogLevel.INFO, "#########\nUser " + str(extensions[0]) + " removed", send_mail=False)
            log_http_result(result)
```

Comment: It worked great!! Thank you so much! Right now it prints only the users I want to remove excluding the one in the "excluded users" list.

Answer (score 0):

First, not your problem, but you don't need `pass` there. It would likely be much cleaner to just negate the condition:

```
if users[0] != excluded_user:
    payloads_user_rm = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "deleteUser", "id": "05", "params": {"username":' + '"' + str(users[0]) + '"' +'}}'

    result = requests.request("GET", ucware_cfg.url_admin_user, data=payloads_user_rm, headers=ucware_cfg.headers)
    Reports.log(Reports.LogLevel.INFO, "#########\nUser " + str(extensions[0]) + " removed", send_mail=False)
    log_http_result(result)
```

Then, from there it's an easy change to use `not in` instead of `!=`:

```
if users[0] not in excluded_user:
    payloads_user_rm = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "deleteUser", "id": "05", "params": {"username":' + '"' + str(users[0]) + '"' +'}}'

    result = requests.request("GET", ucware_cfg.url_admin_user, data=payloads_user_rm, headers=ucware_cfg.headers)
    Reports.log(Reports.LogLevel.INFO, "#########\nUser " + str(extensions[0]) + " removed", send_mail=False)
    log_http_result(result)
```

`in` checks if what's on its left is inside the collection on its right, and `not in` is just a negation of that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, I need to think more in using negations! since I am a beginner, I tend to use only the basic if statements.

Comment: @JoaoReis Just note that you never *need* pass unless you're using it as a placeholder for code that you haven't written yet (`def my_func(): pass`). If you use `pass` for any other purpose, there's likely a better option; like negating the condition.

Comment: I will review all my code now taking that as a consideration! thank you.